# Change color of dialog preference

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is there an easy way to change the color of dialog preferences? The preferences call the constructor of `AlertDialog.Builder()` using the default constructor so it's not possible to apply custom theme, but maybe I could overwrite the default alertDialogTheme with my own alertDialogTheme, but I don't know what attributes use in order to change just the color. If possible I wouldn't create my own drawble just to change a color. It should be possible because for example with Android L, using `colorAccent` some UI change color (not dialog preference yet unfortunately).

Comment: did you try like this: <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>

Comment: @ozi No because I didn't know what I have to change, thanks for the tip. However I think this item is just for list text item not for radio button/checkbox of a dialog preference